# Why should a green card holder use their US-based credit card when traveling abroad?

Tags: usa, greencard, credit-cards

I read on https://www.20minutes.fr/arts-stars/people/2257163-20180418-laeticia-hallyday-retour-saint-barth-nouveau-droit-quitter-territoire-americain ([mirror](http://archive.is/abauO)):

> Quand on a cette fameuse green card, on ne peut pas être absent plus de six mois par an des Etats-Unis. Quand on quitte le territoire américain, il faut bien déclarer ses impôts sur place, conserver une vie active aux Etats-Unis, utiliser une carte bleue américaine, même à l’étranger… On peut demander le reentry permit pour plus d’un an d’absence. C’est un passeport provisoire.

[Translation](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Quand%20on%20a%20cette%20fameuse%20green%20card%2C%20on%20ne%20peut%20pas%20%C3%AAtre%20absent%20plus%20de%20six%20mois%20par%20an%20des%20Etats-Unis.%20Quand%20on%20quitte%20le%20territoire%20am%C3%A9ricain%2C%20il%20faut%20bien%20d%C3%A9clarer%20ses%20imp%C3%B4ts%20sur%20place%2C%20conserver%20une%20vie%20active%20aux%20Etats-Unis%2C%20utiliser%20une%20carte%20bleue%20am%C3%A9ricaine%2C%20m%C3%AAme%20%C3%A0%20l%E2%80%99%C3%A9tranger%E2%80%A6%20On%20peut%20demander%20le%20reentry%20permit%20pour%20plus%20d%E2%80%99un%20an%20d%E2%80%99absence.%20C%E2%80%99est%20un%20passeport%20provisoire.):

> When we have this famous green card, we can not be absent more than six months a year from the United States. **When you leave the US territory, you must** still declare your taxes, keep an active life in the United States, **use a US-based credit card even abroad**... You can ask for the reentry permit for more than a year-long absence. It's a temporary passport.

Why should a green card holder use their US-based credit card when traveling abroad?

Comment: Doesn't seem realistic... I know many Americans living abroad, and they use local CC...

Comment: @dda Americans, or green card holders?

Comment: I have a green card, I have credit cards from several other countries and I use those cards when I'm in those countries. While I report the bank accounts that pay those cards to the IRS I have no idea how anyone would know about the cards themselves nor why they would care. If you have both foreign currency and expenses in that currency it would be idiotic to pay those expenses from a US dollar account instead, and I don't see why anyone would care about the means by which you pay your foreign expenses with your foreign money.

Comment: @Dennis "why they would care" -> proving you're still active in the US. But perhaps it's a useless precaution, or there could be other motivations, I don't know, hence the question :-)

Comment: It may be a way for someone who is out of the US for months at a time to keep an active US credit history????